# C#: What's the difference between an "Obsolete" function and "Deprecated" function?

Tags: c#, function, deprecated, difference, obsolete

C# has attribute called "Obsolete" to indicate a function should no longer be used. While in .net API specifications, when a class/function is out-dated, we say this is "deprecated". So I wonder about the differences between "Obsolete" and "Deprecated".

1. If they mean the same thing, we don't need 2 words, right?
2. If they mean different thing, why sometimes it seems they're talking on the same concept?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As per [english.stackexchange.com](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87887/what-is-the-difference-between-obsolete-and-deprecate-in-computer-science)

> I don't think that there is a strictly adhered-to distinction enforced
>   within the field of computer science. But in most contexts that I have
>   read, **deprecated is more or less a "marker", saying that it should not
>   be used, something else that has the same effect has been created**, and
>   it is soon to be deleted. It may still work as expected (read the last
>   paragraph on why I say may), but it will vanish soon. This is
>   intentionally done as part of the software development life cycle when
>   transitioning from one system to another--all of the functionality of
>   the old system is maintained in order to ensure that all past programs
>   still work, and it gives the developers time to transition their code
>   over to the new system.
>
> **Obsolete means that it no longer works as expected, or doesn't do
>   anything at all**. This is different from non-functional, as it implies
>   that it was rendered so by a new functionality, or its function is
>   simply no longer relevant under the new parameters.
>
> The line between these two terms gets blurred when a function is both
>   deprecated and obsolete. Most of the time, an obsolete function gets
>   deprecated, since it is preferable to deter developers from using it,
>   and to delete it. Since it is generally advisable not to use a
>   deprecated function, whether or not said function is also obsolete is
>   irrelevant, and thus the conflation of the two terms.